# JSTL URI Exception on Tomcat 10

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jstl, tomcat10

I am working through an exercise to use the JSTL library in displaying an ArrayList, and up until this part I was having no issues. After the Maven project conversion and the addition of the JSTL dependency in the pom.xml, I am getting the common error:

> The absolute uri: [http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core] cannot be
> resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this
> application

I understand in some of the other occurrences of this question, Tomcat 10 requires the below as the dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I am still not able to fix the error. Please see the necessary project files below.

**ControllerServlet.java**

```
package org.acr;

import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ControllerServlet
 */
public class ControllerServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private ArrayList<String> bookTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
       
    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public ControllerServlet() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        bookTitles.add("Lord of the Files");
        bookTitles.add("A Tale of Two Servers");
        bookTitles.add("To Catch a Throw");
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        request.setAttribute("book_titles", bookTitles);
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/BookList.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        PrintWriter output = response.getWriter();
        
        String title = request.getParameter("title");
        String author = request.getParameter("author");
        
        output.println("Book Title: " + title);
        output.println("Book Author: " + author);
    }

}
```

**BookList.jsp**

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

<c:forEach items="${book_titles}" var="item">
    <p>Book: ${item}</p>
</c:forEach>

</body>
</html>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>BookStore</groupId>
  <artifactId>BookStore</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <release>17</release>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <dependencies>    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet.jsp.jstl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee" xmlns:web="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jakartaee/web-app_5_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="5.0">
  <display-name>BookStore</display-name>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.acr.ControllerServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ControllerServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/books/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Clean Install:

```
<pre>[<font color="#12488B"><b>INFO</b></font>] <b>------------------------------------------------------------------------</b>
[<font color="#12488B"><b>INFO</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>BUILD FAILURE</b></font>
[<font color="#12488B"><b>INFO</b></font>] <b>------------------------------------------------------------------------</b>
[<font color="#12488B"><b>INFO</b></font>] Total time:  6.480 s
[<font color="#12488B"><b>INFO</b></font>] Finished at: 2022-10-06T17:11:13-04:00
[<font color="#12488B"><b>INFO</b></font>] <b>------------------------------------------------------------------------</b>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] Failed to execute goal <font color="#2AA1B3">org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:wa</font><font color="#26A269">r</font> <b>(default-war)</b> on project <font color="#2AA1B3">BookStore</font>: <font color="#C01C28"><b>Execution default-war of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war failed: Unable to load the mojo &apos;war&apos; in the plugin &apos;org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2&apos; due to an API incompatibility: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: Cannot access defaults field of Properties</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>-----------------------------------------------------</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>realm =    plugin&gt;org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>urls[0] = file:/home/ats-admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-war-plugin/2.2/maven-war-plugin-2.2.jar</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>urls[1] = file:/home/ats-admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/reporting/maven-reporting-api/2.0.6/maven-reporting-api-2.0.6.jar</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>urls[2] = file:/home/ats-admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/doxia/doxia-sink-api/1.0-alpha-7/doxia-sink-api-1.0-alpha-7.jar</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>urls[3] = file:/home/ats-admin/.m2/repository/commons-cli/commons-cli/1.0/commons-cli-1.0.jar</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>urls[4] = file:/home/ats-admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interactivity-api/1.0-alpha-4/plexus-interactivity-api-1.0-alpha-4.jar</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>urls[5] = file:/home/ats-admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/maven-archiver/2.5/maven-archiver-2.5.jar</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>urls[6] = file:/home/ats-admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-io/2.0.2/plexus-io-2.0.2.jar</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>urls[7] = file:/home/ats-admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-archiver/2.1/plexus-archiver-2.1.jar</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>urls[8] = file:/home/ats-admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-interpolation/1.15/plexus-interpolation-1.15.jar</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>urls[9] = file:/home/ats-admin/.m2/repository/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>urls[10] = file:/home/ats-admin/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.3.1/xstream-1.3.1.jar</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>urls[11] = file:/home/ats-admin/.m2/repository/xpp3/xpp3_min/1.1.4c/xpp3_min-1.1.4c.jar</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>urls[12] = file:/home/ats-admin/.m2/repository/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0/plexus-utils-3.0.jar</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>urls[13] = file:/home/ats-admin/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-filtering/1.0-beta-2/maven-filtering-1.0-beta-2.jar</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>Number of foreign imports: 1</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] 
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <font color="#C01C28"><b>-----------------------------------------------------</b></font>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] 
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] -&gt; <b>[Help 1]</b>
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] 
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the <b>-e</b> switch.
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] Re-run Maven using the <b>-X</b> switch to enable full debug logging.
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] 
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[<font color="#C01C28"><b>ERROR</b></font>] <b>[Help 1]</b> http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
</pre>
```

Comment: That can happen if your build system is broken. If you're using an IDE, ensure that there are no errors nor red crosses whatsoever over all place in the project. Let your build system produce a WAR file. Inspect it with a ZIP tool. The JSTL libraries must be in its /WEB-INF/lib folder. If not, then that totally explains the observable problem.

Comment: Thank you. Would it be possible to rebuild as Maven project or will it need to be coded again then converted to Maven project?

Comment: That cannot be answered based on the information provided so far. You still haven't confirmed or disproved or perhaps questioned the hints given in my previous comment.

Comment: I checked in the file system and the Eclipse IDE Project Viewer and I don't see the WAR file. Since I don't see WAR file, I assume I would need to build a brand new version. Update Project doesn't seem to have created the needed WAR file.

Comment: Ah, you're using Eclipse. Excellent. To get the Eclipse-generated one, rightclick project > Export > Web > WAR file. To get the Maven-generated one, look in /target subfolder for the file with .war extension.

Comment: The target directory doesn't have a WAR file, so I would need to generate via Eclipse and move to there? Since the XML tagging in the pom xml file doesn't seem to import the JSTL libraries, I would need to manually place?

Comment: So, Maven doesn't work? Are you absolutely sure you don't have errors or red crosses in the project? You have nowhere confirmed or disproved that. In any case, go to cmd/terminal and run `mvn clean install` from project root just to see what exactly happens.

Comment: The IDE Project Viewer doesn't show any failures. I have updated the post with the thrown exceptions after running clean install.